# No such file or Directory. But only when running through a shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a very basic shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
./cod4_Inxded +set dedicated 1 +exec server.cfg +map_rotate
```

Whenever i run `./cod4_Inxded +set dedicated 1 +exec server.cfg +map_rotate` in the bash it works. But when i run the shell script it says

> ./cod4_Inxded No such file or Directory

The shell script and `cod4_Inxded` are in the same folder.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the shell script from another directory, the shell looks for `./cod4_Inxded` in that directory. You probably want to fix that by something like

```
#!/bin/sh
"$(dirname "$0")/cod4_Inxded" +set dedicated 1 +exec server.cfg +map_rotate
```

That will use the directory "$0" (i.e. how ever you called that shell script) is located in and look for `cod4_Inxded` there. But you still get the same error, so this can't be it.

However... maybe `cod4_Indxded` only works when run from that specific directory? Then try changing to the directory first:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
./cod4_Inxded +set dedicated 1 +exec server.cfg +map_rotate
```

This aborts the script in the case of any errors (`set -e`), then changes the current directory to the one the script is located in, and then runs `./cod4_Inxded` from the same directory.

Comment: This doesn't work. Even when i type in the full path manualy it will fail. It might be because `cod4_Inxded`need's 32bit libaries.But I installed them.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this `bash $(pwd)/cod4_Inxded.sh` with `./cod4_Inxded`,
It will **work** :)